# Error trying to install pipelight

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, wine, pipelight

I try to install pipelight but I get an error msg. What can I do about it?

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pipelight-multi : Depends: wine-staging
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This must be solved if you change your download server in System Settings -> Software & Updates.

Comment: It says you need to install `wine-staging`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the proper repo. Run the following commands to resolve the error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
```

If you get the same error, run the following command to see what the issue is:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-staging
```

This should provide more precise info regarding what needs to be installed or what dependencies are not available. Please post this info to receive further assistance.